# Как воспроизвести записанное камерой видео

Tags: android, android-camera

Видео, записанное с помощью `MediaRecorder`, которое записывается в приложении, воспроизвести не получается через `VideoView`.

Пишу видео с камеры так:

```
 private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

    camera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_video.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

затем в этом же пакете пробую его проиграть:

```
      public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


    String videoSource = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_pkg.camera/files/my_video.mp4";

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();

   }
}
```

но получаю:

> Невозможно проиграть видео

Comment: вы уверены, что видео лежит по этому пути `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_pkg.camera/files/my_video.mp4"`?

Comment: File f = new File(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/");
        f.mkdirs();     -- показывает что есть такой файл с таким названием

Comment: Файл там лежит? вы проверили? ручками, через файловый менеджер

Comment: Как я туда могу попасть ? На моем устройстве нету  root прав - а если получу то потеряю гарантию

Comment: это путь на SD карте, а не в памяти устройства, туда не надо рут права

Comment: но у меня нету SD   карты я пишу во внутреннее хранилище

Comment: есть эмулируемая сд-карта. Туда рут доступ не нужен. Вы оттуда пытаетесь читать. Не знаю, када вы пишете, но читать вы пытваетесь с эмулируемой сд-карты

Comment: А вот пишете вы действительно во внутреннюю память. `getFilesDir` возвращает путь к папке приложения во внутренней памяти. Посмотрите в отладчике, куда вы пишете, и откуда читаете файл, и поймете, что я имею в виду

Comment: для чего нужна эмулируемая карта памяти - чтоб писать туда когда нету физической карты на устройство или это сугубо для теста?

Comment: что у вас за телефон? Вы на него когда-нибудь записывали файлы, например, с компа через USB?

Comment: Nexus5 да записывал

Comment: вот записывали вы их на эмулируемую карту памяти. Она представляет собой часть встроенной в устройство памяти, которая выглядит, как SD-карта.

Comment: как получить путь к видео в пакете (во внутринее хранилище)    String videoSource = getPackageName()+"files/my_video.mp4";    ?

Comment: так же, как вы его получили для записи видео `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_video.mp4"`

Answer (score 1):

Замените 
String videoSource = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_pkg.camera/files/my_video.mp4";
на 
String videoSource = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_video.mp4";